# m2m_changed Signal in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have two apps, A and B

The models.py of A is:-

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The models.py of B is:-

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am trying to use m2m_changed Signal to do something whenever a new event is added to a given Channel instance.

The problem is that i am unable to find a way to know the id of the event, when it is added to an instance of Channel.
I checked the docs :- 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

There is pk_set . But the problem is that it is showing the ids of previously added events as well , when i add a new event to a given instance of Channel. I just want to know the id of latest added event.

How is this possible?
Hope my question is clear...
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me...

```
def event_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == "post_add" and kwargs["model"] == Event:
        # instance.events.latest('pk') is the latest event

m2m_changed.connect( event_handler, sender= Channel.events.through )
```